# custom css in minimal theme

Tags: css, jekyll

I am sorry if this is a very basic question, I am new to css. I am using the minimal theme and I would like to make modifications to the stylesheet. I created the file `/assets/css/style.scss` and below

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
```

I added

```
p{
  color: green;
}
h1{
  color: green;
}
h2{
  color: green;
}
h3{
  color: green;
}
```

which does not work. What is the problem? My site is at https://github.com/mafaldadias/mafaldadias.github.io

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do not close vote this question! There is nothing wrong with this question. 'Does not appear to be about programming'???? I don't understand you guys/girls...

Answer (score 1):

You are not using CSS, you're using SCSS (also called SASS) you will need to compile it to CSS if you want to use it directly in the HTML. You will need to use some SASS compiler like node-sass. If you are a beginner I recommend you to use Koala because is very easy to use and have a dummy GUI

http://koala-app.com/

Comment: I see. In the instructions of the minimal theme it says "Add any custom CSS (or Sass, including imports) you'd like immediately after the @import line" so I assumed this should work.

Comment: Also I thought external stylesheet files should not contain any HTML tags.

Comment: Yes, they tell you where to put your custom code but you should compile it somehow. If the theme have a compile CSS try editing it and put your custom CSS in the bottom of the file. Or just create a new CSS file and link it into the html file after the CSS of the theme to override the theme styles

Comment: This is not true. Sass is automatically converted to css: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/

Comment: I recommend that you do not answer questions by guessing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In contradiction to the other people who have answered, I have actually downloaded your repo and got it to work on the latest version of Jekyll (in less than a minute). Here is what I have done...

I created a new SCSS and called it additional.scss (in the /assets/css/ directory). It looked like this:

```
---
---

p{
  color: green;
}
h1{
  color: green;
}
h2{
  color: green;
}
h3{
  color: green;
}
```

I referenced both CSS files in the layout (default), like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/style.css?v=" | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/additional.css?v=" | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">
```

Note that Jekyll converts SASS to CSS natively, so you do not need any extra configuration for that. Also note that this solution (two CSS files) allows for theme updates.

Happy Jekylling!

Answer (score -2):

You had linked your CSS like;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/style.css?v=" | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">
```

But your file is like `style.scss`, I think due to this it is not reflecting. Try changing this. Try changing it like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/style.scss?v=" | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">
```